# VIm - How to remove right margin

Tags: vim

How do I remove the right margin in Vim? It seems to be adding a carriage return and line feed (column 80?) whenever I save a file as .txt or .md. This doesn't happen if I save the file with no extension, but I want to be able to edit .txt files.

I've tried :set nowrap but this doesn't have the desired effect. I also commented out everything in my .gvimrc file in case I inadvertently did something there but no luck with that approach.

Comment: Start your vim with `vim -i NONE -u NONE` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: That removed the problem. So starting vim this way bypasses viminfo an gvimrc? I'm not sure why this works but commenting out my gvimrc file doesn't.

Comment: it might be the `.vimrc`, not the `.gvimrc`. Both are applied on GVim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by commenting out the following line in the vimrc_example.vim file:

```
" autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78
```

Here's the path to the file on my machine:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\vimrc_example.vim
```

I'm using gVim.

Answer (score 1):

The text filetype in Vim sets the `textwidth` option to 78 by default, which has the effect of splitting lines. If you remove the `textwidth` option by setting it to zero, Vim will stop splitting lines. You can remove textwidth by hand with

`:set textwidth=0`

or you could add something like

`autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=0`

to your `.vimrc`.

Comment: I get an "unknown option" error if I try :set linewidth=0. I tried adding the autocmd command to my .gvimrc file and it didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Sorry - I'd typoed linewidth for textwidth, duh :-( Fix in an edit. For the autocmd, I tested that in .vimrc using command line Vim. Might be worth trying .vimrc rather than .gvimrc.

Answer (score 0):

With the current monitor sizes (4K and bigger) the 78 character rule is not valid anymore (valid in the era before the 21" CRT monitors)

I tried the solution by Jon, but it did not work for git commit messages.

I had to change the `.vimrc` line to

```
autocmd FileType * setlocal textwidth=0
```

Now it works for any file type.